# Dynamic list view with dynamic adapter with click event for each item

Tags: android

I am fetching data from database in ArrayList. In database we have country name, shop name, so on list view I want to display country name then Related shop name with check box. Suppose if there is 5 country then it should display data for 5 country and if 2 country then it should display data for two country.

I have tried and created custom adapter but I am not getting click event for different shop with different country.

Comment: Please post your code to be able to assist.

Comment: Follow this article http://www.thepcwizard.in/2012/09/android-creating-custom-listview-for.html or paste your code.

Answer (score 0):

Interaction with individual views inside a `ListView` is very common in Android any I suggest you study a bit about how `ListView`s work.

[Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) is a tutorial (with code) that helped with understand more about `ListViews`. It also has an example with each list item showing alongside a checkbox. That may be exactly what you need.

Comment: No the basic list view I know and I handled click event but here I a facing problem because list is created dynamically and I am not getting click events for items

Comment: If you are populating your "Country" name inside a textview (which is the row layout of your listview), you can register the myTextView.setOnClickListener in your code. ListViews are mostly dynamically generated and you need to implement the OnClickListeners for the items inside the row layout of your listview.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.app_custom_list, null);
    }

    Application app = items.get(position);
    v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You clicked here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
}
```